# Is it possible to scp asynchronously?

Tags: linux, scp

I am in the process of migrating my data to a new server (from one Linux box to another), and I left my laptop running overnight whilst I scp'd barely half of my data between the two.

It would be a great help if I could continue the rest of the scp process asynchronously so that I can set the process running and log off/forget about it until it's done.

Typically I run async processes in the terminal by adding **&** after the command, but this doesn't seem to apply to scp.

Can scp be done in the way I'd like?

Answer (score 4):

a) Use `screen` or `tmux` to put operations in the background.

b) Use `rsync` for this purpose instead of `scp`. It is much more useful as you can easily resume transfers if they fail.

c) Normally, you wouldn't use your laptop as intermediary station if possible but copy directly from one server to another. `tmux`/`screen` is even more useful in that scenario.

Comment: Thank you Sven. I have no choice but to use my laptop as the intermediary - both servers are accessibly by SSH only. So I SSH into one of them, and scp to the other, which is why I want to just be able to disconnect my laptop once the process has started.

Comment: I don't believe that this would work. If you need your laptop as intermediary machine to copy the data, it needs to be online the whole time. `tmux` would just reliably put the operation into the background.

Comment: No, the laptop is not the intermediary - the data never touches the laptop. I am SSH'ing into server A and then setting off an scp command to server B. I then want to disconnect and leave them to it. I believe your suggestion of using tmux might do the job: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Comment: Yes, it's perfect for this.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop isn't involved in the actual copy, except to ssh in, use `nohup` and background the process when you start it.

`nohup` causes the process to ignore the hangup signal.  Just output to a log file to monitor it.

Example:

```
nohup rsync -arv /foo user@servername:/bar > output.log 2>&1 &
```